# Forge viewer globaloffset change breaks moving in and select

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have an app that uses the forge viewer to display a 3d model. In that model, we save camera positions at certain points.

Sometimes a model will be updated, adding an element for example. Now if we load the camera positions, they seem to have 'moved'. After some investigation, we found that for the 2 models, the globaloffset differs. If we load the updated model, with the globaloffset of the previous model, then the camera positions match again.

So i guess the globaloffset is calculated to match the center of the model on 0,0,0 and by adding an element, the center switches, causing an offset of the camera positions.

I updated the app to load the model always with the first globaloffset. So far so good.

However, once we do that, moving the model really close behaves weird. If the offset is changed a little, then the model shifts a bit left-right when you get it close using the scrollwheel, instead of a smooth transition. And when the offset is changed a lot, it seems that getting the model really close is not even possible anymore (by using the scrollwheel). Furthermore, when really close to the model, selection of an element is of. IE. i click at an element and the element next to it is selected (or none at all).

Which makes me wonder about 2 things:

- Is globaloffset usable to translate the position of the model a bit, or should we leave it alone?
- Is there an other easy way of translating xyz of the complete model?

Answer (score 0):

The global offset is mainly used to avoid large floating point numbers in the geometry data (when the model is "far away from the origin"). Customizing the offset value should still be possible without any side-effects, though, so if you're still running into issues there, consider sending a bug report to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`.

There's also the `placementTransform` (`THREE.Matrix4`) option you can set when loading a model but I think that one only applies rotation/scale.